# when using itextpdf , html2pdf I got this error?

Tags: java, android, itext, html2pdf

I am using     implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:2.1.3' to convert html to pdf file in my android application it worked good at android 9 but when using android 4 or 5 , 6 I have error

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some more context for your problem?

Comment: I mean when I use com.itextpdf:html2pdf:2.1.3 library for convert html file  to pdf file it worked good at  Android 8.0 (API level 26)  or heigher othewise 
I have the top error at line 
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdf, properties); @NatFar

Comment: Could you share the sample code you're working on?